# Como mostrar só maior valor após .count() no Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Tenho um df que tem como origem uma planilha de vendas.

Fiz uma filtragem para pegar as colunas "ID Loja" (Que retorna o nome da loja), "Produto" (Que retorna o nome do produto daquela linha) e "Quantidade" (Que é a quantidade do produto)

Fiz um groupby com o "ID Loja" e "Produto", seguido de uma contagem para verificar a recorrência. Até aqui ok, mas ele retorna todos os produto, o que eu queria é o produto mais recorrente de cada loja (ID Loja):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

No seu data frame, utilize o .max() na coluna produto, acho que isso pode te ajudar se é realmente o que eu entendi da pergunta.

Eu não consigo ver a imagem.